# External Data Source deployment (Salesforce Connect)

Tags: odata, salesforce-connect

I have configured the External Data Sources using Odata 4.0,and i need to move this setup to UAT environment .What is best approach to do this ?

Deployment OR manually create setup in UAT environment ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Salesforce has exposed better Metadata API Coverage Report . For V44.0 the coverage report is [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/metadata-coverage/44)

From the report shown in the below screenshot , it sounds like it has metadata API support and changeset support . I would simply avoid manual move and deploy them .

[image]